# Typescript type order breaking change between 1.7 and 1.8

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

Visual Studio Cordova app with the following typescript source structure :

```
/src
  /app
    /appsub1
      appsub1.ts -> 4 : 7
    /appsub2
      appsub2.ts -> 5 : 6
    app.ts -> 3 : 5
  /mod1
    /mod1sub1
      mod1sub1.ts -> 7 : 4
    mod1.ts -> 6 : 3
  baseclass1.ts -> 1 : 1
  baseclass2.ts -> 2 : 2
```

the numbers after the file names are the order they are included in the output .js file when compiled using typescript -> v1.7.6 : v1.8.3
Dependencies are setup so that base classes are always 'higher' up the structure
Note that 1.8.3 is including the sub directories in reverse alpha order which breaks the dependency structure
1.8.3 is also defining __extends at the top which 1.7.6 did not

Is there some config element that needs to be updated when moving from 1.7 to 1.8 or is order of inclusion just completely undependable ?

Answer (score 0):

> is order of inclusion just completely undependable

It is undependable in subtle ways if you don't use modules : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

That said you can use a `references` hack : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#javascript-generation

Comment: Well it was dependable  up to 1.8 - walking the source structure top to bottom in alphabetical order files first directories second.  In 1.8 we have top to bottom files 1st in alpha order with directories second in reverse alpha order.

Comment: Adding references to the already brittle imports just serves to double the maintenance nightmare.  To resolve the order issue I added another directory level which of course meant finding and changing any affected  import paths - this is such a step backwards.